# Операция коньюкции и сдвига,СИ

Tags: c

Есть программа, которая переводит число в 2-ое представление в виде строки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX sizeof(num) * 8 + 1
void ltoab (long num,char s[]){
    int i;
    s[MAX]='\0';
    for(i=MAX-1;i>=0;i--){
        s[i]=(num&1)+'0';
        num=num>>1;
    }
    printf("%s\n",s );
}

int main(void){
    long num;
    char *s=(char*)malloc(33*sizeof(char*));
    scanf("%d",&num);
    ltoab(num,s);

}
```

Как понять строку:

```
s[i]=(num&1)+'0';
        num=num>>1;
```

Где `num` - любое число. Я знаю, что берется число `num` и число 1 в двоичном представлении, между ними операция '&'=>получается новое число. Для чего это?

Comment: num&1 Так вырезается младший бит. Например: 1010 & 0001 = 0; 1011 & 0001 = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Что здесь происходит?**

Этот кусок кода переводит *2-ое представление числа*, находящегося в целочисленной переменной `num` в массив из символов `char s[]` (т.е. проще говоря, в строку).

---

**Пояснение алгоритма**

Фактически этот кусок кода определяет самый младший бит самого младшего байта целочисленной переменной `num` и переводит его в соответствующий символ массива из `char` (`char s[]`), т.е. бит со значением `0` в символ `'0'` и бит со значение `1` в символ `'1'` (посредством `s[i] = (num & 1) + '0';`)

Затем переходит к следующему биту (за счет операции побитового сдвига на 1 бит вправо `num = num >> 1;`). Таким образом, получая двоичное представление целочисленной переменной `num` в виде в массива из символов, который в дальнейшем, например, можно вывести на экран, тем саммым наглядно проиллюстрировав двоичное представление числа, которое хранится в переменной.

---

**Рассмотрим на примере**

Пусть у нас имеется некоторое число в десятичной системе счисления, например, `9`, переведем его в двоичную систему счисления `1001` (я упустил опережающие 0-ые биты, т.к. они будут делать пример громоздким). Дак вот, в памятки компьютера все числа (да и вообще все) хранятся в двоичном виде.

1. Выполняя операцию `побитового И` (`&`) для нашего числа `9` (`1001` - в двоичном виде) c `1` (которая в двоичном представлении совпадает с десятичным, т.е. `0001`), таким образом получим результат `0001`, затем мы этот результат, фактически, переводим обратно в десятичную систему счиления (на самом деле компьютер так не делает, но мы представим так для прояснения идеи) и получим число `1`, которое прибавим к коду символа `'0'` (который равен `48` согласно [таблице символо ASCII](http://book.itep.ru/10/ascii.htm), глядя на которую видно, что код символа `'1'` равен `49` и для его получения достаточно к символу `'0'` прибавить число `1`), тем самым получим символ с кодом `49`, т.е. симмвол `'1'`.
2. Затем сдвигаем наше число `9` на *1 бит вправо*, т.е. `9 >> 1` на выходе даст `0100` (т.е. `1001` -> `0100`), а затем см. п.1 (т.е. теперь мы к `0100` снова применим операцию `побитового И` с `1`, тем самым получа результатом двоичное число `0000` (что есть `0` в десятичном виде), затем прибавим к результату код символа `'0`' тем самым ничего не поменяв, в итоге получа символ `'0'` и так далее).

Таким образом, имея начальное двоичное число `1001` (т.е. десятичное `9`), мы сначала узнали какой у этого числа самый младший бит (`1001 & 1 = 1`), что проще говоря - значение самой правой цифры в двоичном представлении. Затем *сдвинули на 1 бит вправо* `1001` -> `0100` и снова узнали значение младшего бита у получившегося числа (`0100 & 1 = 0`) и так далее пока не пройдем все биты начального числа.

Т.е. упрощенно можно выделить следующие итерации для `9` (`1001`):

1. `1001 & 1 = 1`, `1001 >> 1 = 0100`
2. `0100 & 1 = 0`, `0100 >> 1 = 0010`
3. `0010 & 1 = 0`, `0010 >> 1 = 0001`
4. `0001 & 1 = 1`

Comment: как понять самый младший бит?

Comment: @dfd Одну минуту, сейчас в ответе снизу поясню примером

Comment: @dfd После приведения примера идея стала  ясно или попробовать еще больше расписать? (я сейчас отойду ненадолго так что прочитаю комментарий чуток попозднее)

Comment: ну если можно уточнение,Получается у нас младший бит в примере с 9 =1?а если допустим берем число 2,то получается младший бит равен 0?

Comment: @dfd Да, для `9` (`1001`) младший бит - это `1`, а для 2 (`0010`) младший бит - это `0`.

Comment: @dfd Я в конец ответа сейчас добавил еще немного пояснений, чтобы стало еще понятнее - гляньте.

Comment: тогда вроде понятно)еще раз спасибо за подробное объяснение)

Comment: @dfd Не за что :) После моего ответа вы так подправили текст вопроса, что теперь кажется, что додуматься до этого отвечающему было вообще легко (раньше был вопрос в духе:  "А что здесь такое происходит?")  :D

Comment: именно так и было:D осталось попрактиковаться)