# Как работает поразрядный оператор &

Tags: c#

```
 // Показать биты, составляющие байт
    int t;
    byte val;

    val = 123;
    for (t = 128; t > 0; t = t / 2)
    {
        if ((val & t) != 0) Console.Write("1 ");
        if ((val & t) == 0) Console.Write("0 ");
    }
```

Результат: 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

1. Тут блок for (t = 128; t > 0; t = t / 2) как может выполнятся если переменная t изначально больше нуля и зачем нужен t = t / 2
2. if ((val & t) != 0) Console.Write("1 "); Поразрядный оператор & проверяет каждый бит переменных val и t в двоичной системе, или только последнюю?

Подскажите как эта программа работает?

Comment: цикл `for` по русски следует читать: `t=128; ПОКА t>0 делаем t=t/2` так что он выполняется от 128 до тех пор пока t>0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не совсем обычная форма вывода двоичного представления числа от старших бит к младшему.

> Тут блок for (t = 128; t > 0; t = t / 2) как может выполнятся

А что вас здесь смущает? `t` будет последовательно `128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 0`. Почему 0 - т.к. деление целочисленное то остаток будет отброшен.

> Поразрядный оператор & проверяет каждый бит переменных val и t в двоичной системе

Он делает логическое `И` для 2 чисел. Например 9 и 3 будет 1, т.к. 9 это 1001 3 это 11, а в результате будут 1 там где они есть в двух числах одновременно - то есть 1.

Если теперь в целом о программе - то она берёт и проверяет последовательно включён ли бит от 8 (128) до 1 (1). Если да - то выводит 1 иначе 0.

Comment: Правда это все можно сделать несколько в более общем виде, как [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495655/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%98), например (пример на C++, но на C# можно сделать аналогично).

Answer (score 0):

Сам код программы мягко говоря странный. Вот так попроще. Выполнять ненужное деление на число кратное двум, как в вашем примере - неправильно, так как операция сдвига бита выполняется значительно быстрее.

```
int val = 123;
for(int i = 7; i > -1; i--)
{
    if((val & (1<<i)) == 0)
        Console.Write("0");
    else
        Console.Write("1");
}
```